# Expected value of hand raises

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose that in a coffeehouse there are $\text{Poi}(10)$ guests, each one of the guests drinks $\text{Poi(}1)$ cups of coffee, and raises his hand, independently,  $\text{Poi}(1)$ amout of times.

The number of guests, the amount of coffee that each guest drink, and the number of hand raises each guest perform - are all independent.

Suppose that in the same day, no cups of coffee have been sold. Given that information, calculate the expected value of the total hand raises.

Well, my attempt was to let $X\sim \text{Poi}(10)$ be the number of guests at the coffeehouse, let $Y$ be the number of cups of coffee and $Z$ be the number of hand raises.

Since the hand raises are independent where each one has $\text{Poi}(1)$ distribution , and there are $X$ guests, we can conclude that $Z\sim \text{Poi}(X)$. Similarly, $Y\sim\text{Poi}(X)$. So if I understand correctly, I need to find the value of $E[Z|Y=0]$

How can I proceed  from here? How the fact the $Y=0$ affects $Z$?

Comment: The fact that $Y=0$ is evidence for $X$ being small.  User Bayes Theorem to re-estimate the probability distribution for $X$ and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bayes' theorem we get that:

$$P(X=k|Y=0)=\frac{e^{-\frac{10}{e}}(\frac{10}{e})^k}{k!}$$

Therefore, $Z\sim\text{Poi}(\text{Poi}(\frac{10}{e}))$, so $E[Z]=\frac{10}{e}$

Comment: I evaluated all the infinite sums adnd came to the same answer, so this looks right to me (although I don't understand how it works).